# Interpretation of the words "constructor's class" in §12.6.2/2 in the C++11 Standard

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

As a sanity check, could someone confirm if the words **constructor's class** in this statement of §12.6.2/2 refer to a delegating constructor?

12.6.2/2 statement:

> Unless the mem-initializer-id names the constructor’s class, a
>   non-static data member of the constructor’s class, or a direct or
>   virtual base of that class, the mem-initializer is ill-formed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. It says that it's valid to have the same class as the mem-initializer-id, which would make the current constructor a delegating constructor. This is explained further in 12.6.2/6:

> If a mem-initializer-id designates the constructor’s class,
>   it shall be the only mem-initializer; the constructor is a delegating constructor, and the constructor selected
>   by the mem-initializer is the target constructor.

Comment: I'm accepting your answer, simply because I've got it before the others. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

They do. From the [delegating constructors proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n1986.pdf):

> Change §12.6.2(2) as follows:
>
> (...) Unless the *mem-initializer-id* names a non-static data member of the constructor's class, **the constructor's class,** or  a a direct or virtual base of that class, the *mem-initializer* is ill-formed. (...)

The newly inserted text is underlined instead of bold in the proposal, but I can't do that in markdown. It goes on further:

> *A mem-initializer-list* can delegate to another constructor (the *target constructor*) of the constructor's class using any name that denotes the constructor's class itself. (...)

This wording is found, with minor changes, in the final standard as 12.6.2 (6):

> *A mem-initializer-list* can delegate to another constructor of the constructor's class using any *class-or-decltype* that denotes the constructor's class itself. (...)

So yes, all of this comes from the delegating constructors proposal and refers specifically to constructor delegation.

Answer (score 2):

Throughout [class.base.init], "constructor" refers to the same "constructor" introduced in paragraph 1:

> In the definition of a constructor for a class, initializers for
>   direct and virtual base subobjects and non-static data members can be
>   specified by a *ctor-initializer*, which has the form [...]

Paragraph 2 saying that in the definition of *a* constructor, the *mem-initializer-id* (there can be multiple *mem-initializer-id*s in a *mem-initializer-list*) can refer to one of three things:

- the constructor's class, i.e. a delegating constructor (paragraph 6)
- a non-static data member, i.e. `S() : n{5}`
- a direct or virtual base of that class, i.e. `S() : Base(5)` (paragraph 3)